# Is feedback on music book authors on-topic?

Tags: discussion

These appear to be: [Working through George Lawrence Stone's stick control book](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/51575/26407), [Can learning music theory from this book teach me enough to start composing?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/53392/26407), [Is Hanon's "Virtuoso Pianist" good for self-taught musician?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/517/26407).

But my question was closed: [How do musicologists judge Paul Griffiths OBE?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/70029/26407).

Comment: Again, there has to be more to a meta discussion than "X is closed and Y is open so X should be reopened". The only thing in common these questions have is there is a book mentioned in each, but they are all very different.  We can always try to make the site's policies clearer, but just listing questions like this muddies the actual issue with the question that was stated in the comments to your question.

Comment: What's an OBE in this context? I'm only familiar with "Order of the British Empire", a form of knighthood. If that's the sense meant, how could an OBE be related to Music Practice or Theory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the other example questions you point to are along the lines of 'how can this book benefit my musical abilities', from a musical point of view.

Your question is along the lines of "why are these reviewers criticising this author" - when if you read the reviews, it seems that almost none of the criticism is really something we can comment on from a musical point of view, and it's self contained in the reviews. So it's extremely unclear what extra information you want an answer to add.

You could argue that's a quantitative, rather than a categorical distinction. But I still think that it should be clear that this question focused in this way is off-topic for this site; As a question coming from someone who *isn't* new to the site it comes across to me somewhat as a deliberate attempt to troll/waste people's time, and as I've said elsewhere, I'm someone who has strongly defended some of your other questions.

Answer (score 3):

First off, remember that other posts being open is no guide to whether yours will be.

Then look at the questions themselves - yours is entirely asking for opinion, which is definitively off topic here.

Comment: The others do ask for opinion too?

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal No, the other questions are asking for advice based on expert level experience. "Will this work?" is a way to summarize the other questions, while your question is more like "What do you think of this?" Notice the title of this very meta question! You are asking about "feedback about **book authors**". The other questions are asking about **learning music**.